# React Native call a function only once

Tags: react-native, function, call

I'm developing an application using react native in this application I have this function called `addDetails()` this function is executed inside the `functionCombined()` with another function When the user press the button. In this application the `functionCombined()` function will be executed according to each button press. But I want to execute the `addDetails()` function only once, but the `uploadPrices()` function should be executed according to the button press. Is there any way to implement it?

**Basically what I want is to execute the `addDetails()` function only once that is inside the `functionCombined()` function. The `addDetails()` function should be executed on the first button click only after that `addDetails()` function cannot be executed no matter how many times the user clicks the button. Is there any way to implement it?**

```
const functionCombined = () => {
            addDetails(); 
            uploadPrices();  
        }  



const addDetails = () => {
              
            db.transaction(txn => {
                txn.executeSql(
                    `INSERT INTO invoices (name, date) VALUES (? , ?)`,
                    [customerName,text],
                    (sqlTxn, res) => {
                        console.log(`${customerName}, ${text} added successfully `); 
                        
                    }, 
                    error => {
                        console.log('error on adding details ' + error.message);
                    },
                );
            });
    
            alert("Successfully Upload Customer Details"); 
              
        };


    
    <Pressable onPress={functionCombined}>
```

Comment: add a state variable.. set it to true in addDetails() at the end..and have a check if not true then execute addDetails()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just have a flag, to check if the button was clicked, and add the addDetails() inside the flag check, something like:

```
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

const functionCombined = () => {
      if(!buttonClicked){
          addDetails();
          setButtonClicked(true);
       }
      uploadPrices();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the correct answer